# How can I count the time that needs systemd to boot a default target and then graph it?

Tags: boot, systemd, time, parallelism

When I wanted to know how long systemd actually needed to boot the default target, how would I do that ? An then, is it possible to create a graph to show which unit takes how much time to initialize and to what degree they are run in parallel ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `systemd-analyze` built-in tool. You are especially interested in two options: blame and plot

```
systemd-analyze blame
systemd-analyze plot > graph.svg
```

- `blame`:    Print list of running units ordered by time to init
- `plot`:     Output SVG graphic showing service initialization

Answer (score 2):

To find out how long it takes for the system to boot, systemd provides `systemd-analyze`. Without parameters, it will tell you the time to boot.

Calling `systemd-analyze critical-chain` will print a tree of the chain of services that took the longest, while `systemd-analyze blame` will tell you how long each service took independently. Finally, `systemd-analyze plot > boot.svg` will create a little graph that shows everything nicely.

If you want fancier graphs, the Arch Linux wiki has a good article on using [Bootchart](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bootchart), which as its name implies, creates boot graphs.